# Error when sending JSON to Web API if too long

Tags: javascript, json, web, asp.net-web-api

I'm have problems sending a JSON object to a .NET Web API.  I have multi array that I convert into JSON and send to the web service.  The total length of the object is just over 50,000 characters.  If I do a slice on the array everything is fine.  It does not matter what 2 items I send as long as it's less that 2500 characters.

```
   let value = JSON.stringify(this.excelData.results.slice(2, 2));
   axios({
   method: 'post',      
   url: 'http://adminapiSystem.com/api/saveJSONData',
   params: {          
     value: value
    }    
   })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log('Saved')
  }) 
  .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
  
  } )
```

I was under the impression that the max length was 2097152 or 4 meg

my web service is

```
     Public Function PostValue(ByVal value As String) As String
        Dim ret As String = SendDataSQL(value)
        Return ret
    End Function
```

and the error is

```
        xhr.js?b50d:177 POST http://xxxxx/api/saveJSONData?value=    [%7B%22Status%22:%22Active%22,%22DBID%22:%22SB%22,%22ID%22:11691,%22Search%22:null,%22Year_Start%22:2015,%22Year_End%22:3000,%22Enrolled%22:null,%22WithDrawn%22:null,%22Last_Name%22:%22Baer%22,%22First_Name%22:%22Lea%22,%22MI%22:null,%22Suffix%22:null,%22PubMed_ForeName%22:null,%22PubMed_Initials%22:null,%22Email%22:%22Lea.Baer%40stonybrookmedicine.edu%22,%22ORCID%22:null,%22Membership_Type%22:%22Affiliate%22,%22ProgramName%22:%22Non-Programmatically+aligned%22,%22Program_Code%22:%22ZY%22,%22Program_Roles%22:null,%22Search_Term%22:null,%22PMID_New%22:null,%22Harvard_Search_PMIDs%22:null,%22PMID_Current%22:null,%22PMID_Exclude%22:null,%22Affiliations%22:%22Stony+Brook%22,%22Authoring_Names%22:null,%22Basic_Search_String%22:null,%22Send_Email%22:null,%22Custom_Search_String%22:null,%22Academic_Title%22:null,%22Department%22:%22Medicine%22%7D,%7B%22Status%22:%22Active%22,%22DBID%22:%22SB++++++++%22,%22ID%22:11683,%22Search%22:null,%22Year_Start%22:2015,%22Year_End%22:3000,%22Enrolled%22:null,%22WithDrawn%22:null,%22Last_Name%22:%22Bahou%22,%22First_Name%22:%22Wadie%22,%22MI%22:%22F%22,%22Suffix%22:null,%22PubMed_ForeName%22:null,%22PubMed_Initials%22:null,%22Email%22:%22Wadie.bahou%40stonybrookmedicine.edu%22,%22ORCID%22:null,%22Membership_Type%22:%22Affiliate%22,%22ProgramName%22:%22Non-Programmatically+aligned%22,%22Program_Code%22:%22ZY%22,%22Program_Roles%22:null,%22Search_Term%22:null,%22PMID_New%22:null,%22Harvard_Search_PMIDs%22:null,%22PMID_Current%22:null,%22PMID_Exclude%22:null,%22Affiliations%22:%22Stony+Brook%22,%22Authoring_Names%22:null,%22Basic_Search_String%22:null,%22Send_Email%22:null,%22Custom_Search_String%22:null,%22Academic_Title%22:null,%22Department%22:%22Medicine%22%7D,%7B%22Status%22:%22Active%22,%22DBID%22:%22SB++++++++%22,%22ID%22:11685,%22Search%22:null,%22Year_Start%22:2015,%22Year_End%22:3000,%22Enrolled%22:null,%22WithDrawn%22:null,%22Last_Name%22:%22Bakoulis%22,%22First_Name%22:%22Anastasia%22,%22MI%22:null,%22Suffix%22:null,%22PubMed_ForeName%22:null,%22PubMed_Initials%22:null,%22Email%22:%22Anastasia.Bakoulis%40stonybrookmedicine.edu%22,%22ORCID%22:null,%22Membership_Type%22:%22Affiliate%22,%22ProgramName%22:%22Non-Programmatically+aligned%22,%22Program_Code%22:%22ZY%22,%22Program_Roles%22:null,%22Search_Term%22:null,%22PMID_New%22:null,%22Harvard_Search_PMIDs%22:null,%22PMID_Current%22:null,%22PMID_Exclude%22:null,%22Affiliations%22:%22Stony+Brook%22,%22Authoring_Names%22:null,%22Basic_Search_String%22:null,%22Send_Email%22:null,%22Custom_Search_String%22:null,%22Academic_Title%22:null,%22Department%22:%22Surgery%22%7D] 404 (Not Found)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js?b50d:177
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js?b50d:13
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js?5270:52
Promise.then (async)
request @ Axios.js?0a06:61
wrap @ bind.js?1d2b:9
saveAllData @ publication_report.vue?02c8:145
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854
invoker @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2179
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854
Vue.$emit @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3888
click @ QBtn.js?9c40:101
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854
invoker @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2179
original._wrapper @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6917
publication_report.vue?02c8:156 Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
    at settle (settle.js?467f:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js?b50d:62)
```

My web config has

```
       <scripting>
  <webServices>
    <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644" />
  </webServices>
     </scripting>
```

and

```
  <system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" maxUrlLength="10240" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
<customErrors mode="Off" />
 </system.web>
```

One last item-- I'm using HostBuddy as my hosting service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the POST request and the data are in the URL.

The GET maximum length is **2,048 characters** and you will not be able to send more. It's an HTTP limit.

What you can do is to send this data via the **POST** method in **BODY**, **which does not have limits**.

This Axios code should work for you:

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'http://adminapiSystem.com/api/saveJSONData',
  data: {
    value: value
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks-- I did not see that.  I figured that when it said POST that was what was needed changed params to data and now get a CORS error for a POST.  But that's a different issue that should be easier to fix with the hosting company